# Unknown column 'username' in the list field

Tags: mysql

I've got a database called persons_db. When I select PID, it gives no error. Otherwise I get:

"Unknown column 'username' in 'field list"

```
mysql_select_db( "persons_db" ) or die( 'Error'. mysql_error() );
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `persons_db`.`my_table`( .
        `PID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(PID),
        `username` CHAR(15),
        `email` CHAR(15),
        `password` CHAR(15)
        )';

$retval = mysql_query( $sql);

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
    echo'table created';

$sql1 = mysql_query ("SELECT userName FROM my_table",$link);
if (!$sql1)
    echo "error";
```

Comment: 1. Does it really exist? 2. What if you specify it in the exact capitalization?

Comment: I suppose you have a typo. You are using username while creating and userName in select query.

Comment: If you needed backquotes in the CREATE TABLE statement, you probably need backquotes (and exact case matching) in the SELECT statement too.  If you didn't need backquotes, don't use them.

Comment: @Rohan210: SQL is generally case-insensitive except inside quotes.

Comment: sorry i missed up while writing this post but in my application i write username with no capital litters how ever i still got that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_select_db( "persons_db" ) or die( 'Error'. mysql_error() );
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `persons_db`.`my_table`( .
        `PID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY(PID),
        `username` CHAR(15),
        `email` CHAR(15),
        `password` CHAR(15)
        )';

$retval = mysql_query( $sql);

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
    echo'table created';

$sql1 = mysql_query ("SELECT username FROM my_table",$link);
if (!$sql1)
    echo "error";
```

Try that instead, in mysql case sensitivity depends on a few factors not the least the OS you're running it on. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html But being consistent is something you should always try to be.

Also as a side note you may want to consider not using mysql_* functions as they are no longer considered safe and are now deprecated.

Comment: still got an error even after i copied and paste your code

Comment: what is the result when you request `desc my_table`?